# d3js and svg for printing to multiple pages

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have sport schedules that I would like users to be able to print out on 2 or 4 pages. Tournaments with a large amount of teams would produce hard to read text because there isn't much space for it.

Not sure how to produce printable content with d3js, should I specify values for placement and size in pixels, centimetres, percentage? Percentage sounds good but would need to insert a page break element, maybe provide a separate svg for every page. Can't find a good article on how to do this and am wondering if I've missed something.

The code as is should produce lines with text labels, to fit it all on 2 pages the text in the labels would be very small so want to provide a 4 page version. So my question is: What would be the best way to do this?

I'm thinking of providing 4 or 2 svg elements with a page-break-after css style. The shape and dimensions would be roughly letter or a4 landscape and placement units are based on percentages.

**[UPDATE]**

Since [pageSet and page](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-SVG12-20041027/multipage.html) elements seem to be ignored by Firefox (and inkscape) and wrongly interpreted by Chrome I've tried multiple svg's. This seems to print fine on my new but not latest Firefox and Chrome. Code I use is:

```
<html><head>
    <title>Test tournament bracket</title>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <style>
      @media print {
        .noPrint {display:none;}
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="noPrint">
        <h1>Forms and non printable content</h1>
    </div>
    <svg width="70" height="55">
        <text x="10" 
          y="10" font-family="sans-serif" 
          font-size="12px" fill="black">
          Hello
        </text>
    </svg>
    <div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
    <svg width="70" height="55">
        <text x="10" 
          y="10" font-family="sans-serif" 
          font-size="12px" fill="black">
          World
        </text>
    </svg>
  </body></html>
```

Will give that a shot and see how it turns out.

Comment: I would generate a single page SVG and then tile it either in a drawing program or using your printer driver if it supports that.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thank you for your reply. I would like users to print it out on several pages without too much trouble.

Comment: Note that multi-page SVG is a relatively recent specification that isn't that widely supported yet. Converting to PDF instead might be a better choice.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Multiple svg elements on page seems to work, haven't tried it with IE yet (forget about <=8) Will try to implement that. Thank you for your input. I've discovered that pageSet and page elements are indeed not very well supported in browsers (and inkscape)